# How to paste (RGBA mode) an image to another into a specific position?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Using Pillow, `alpha_composite` only works with images of the same size, I'd like to paste a bloc to a specific position keeping its alpha channel.

To be more specific, I would like to copy/paste many times a semi-transparent picture to another one, *over* a background image.

How could you do that with pillow?

Here's my code:

```
el_width, el_height = 100, 300
img = Image.open('partition.png')
img = img.convert("RGBA")

img_rect = Image.new('RGBA', (el_width, el_height), (0, 0, 0, 100))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_rect)
# draw a semi-transparent rectangle:
draw.rectangle((0, 0, el_width, el_height), outline=(50, 155, 50, 155))
del draw

# trying to paste it:
img.paste(img_rect, (10, 10))
img.show()
```

Here's the result, you can see the rectangle is transparent, but its transparency is ignored when using "paste":

[image: problematic image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code can help you

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

foreground_name = 'BFB_Logo.png'
foreground = Image.open(foreground_name)
foreground = foreground.convert('RGBA')

for file_name in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    print(file_name)
    background_name = file_name
    background = Image.open(background_name)

    # set position there
    x = int((background.size[0] / 2) - (foreground.size[0] / 2))
    y = int((background.size[1] / 2) - (foreground.size[1] / 2))

    background = background.convert('RGBA')
    background.paste(foreground, (x, y), mask = foreground)
    background.save('__{}.jpg'.format(background_name.split('.')[0]),'JPEG')

print('Ready')
```

Comment: This is a nice help, I've managed to solve my problem thanks to your help. Congratulations and welcome aboard!